# How would you export lines in a csv file that contain a specific email domain with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, csv

Suppose I have a csv file with four columns: "Employee Number","First Name","Last Name","Email"

How do you export out only the lines that have a particular email domain, such as @acme.com or @contoso.com? So far, this is what I've tried below but I get no output.

```
Import-CSV -Path $SrcFolder\employees.csv | Where-Object {$_.'Email' -Like "@acme.com|@contoso.com"} | Export-CSV -Path $DestFolder\employees_out.csv -notypeinfo
```

Comment: the `-like` operator **_does not use regex_**. [*grin*] try the `-match` operator instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the -match operator instead.  This works:

```
Import-CSV -Path $SrcFolder\employees.csv | 
    Where-Object {$_.'Email' -imatch "@acme.com|@contoso.com"}
```

And if you don't want to mess with upper/lower, use -imatch.  This works too:

```
Import-CSV -Path $SrcFolder\employees.csv | 
    Where-Object {$_.'Email' -imatch "@acme.com|@contoso.com"}
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! The 'imatch' parameter does exactly what I needed. I was stuck trying to use the '-like' and wasn't exploring any other options.